# How do I to keep focus on window and ontop until closed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making my own a pop up window in jframe. For anyone who's wondering I'm not using the prebuilt popup window because I cant customize some aspects of it. I would like this window to have focus until the user has closed it using a button I made (pretty simple stuff).

```
    private class SwingAction extends AbstractAction {
    public SwingAction() {
        putValue(NAME, btnEnter.getText());
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

For reference, you might seem something like this in other popup windows or something like a file picker.

I have tried making a focus listener that when the window loses focus it requests it again but that didn't work. I also tried

```
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

But that only resulted in other windows having focus when clicked on but the other one still being on top. I am trying to get it to have both of those (on top and focus) while the window is still visual.

Comment: _I'm not using the prebuilt popup window_ - are you talking about the JOptionPane? If so then use the component name so we don't need to guess what you are talking about. If you need a child window then use a modal JDialog, not a JFrame..

Comment: I made my own option pane because I neede some extra things on the window but I just want to know how I could force a window(jframe) to always have focus and be at frount

Comment: Your application should never have complete control of the desktop. The user should be able to use other applications while your application is open. `I made my own option pane` - I don't know what that means. A JOptionPane or modal JDialog will always display on top of the frame until it is closed. So unless the user decides to switch to another application you will have focus. If you leave your application and  return the option pane or dialog will still have focus. Not sure what your problem is. Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem.